# Trying to filter values of an array within an array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

I am new to MongoDB and I'm trying to filter values of an array within an array. An example of the schema is below. The schema is basically a dump of a 3 tiered Dictionary with a simple object of scalars as the leaf node.

The "I" member contains an array of documents (outer array) of key-value pairs with a string key (k), and the value (v) is an array of documents (middle array) of key-value pairs with a date as the key and value is another dictionary, which isn't part of this question.

Basically, what I need to do is retrieve the most recent data from the middle array (Date, key-value) for a given value of the outer array (string, key-value).

```
(Collection Sample)
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eacfbe62758834aefdec003"),
    "UserId" : UUID("46942978-29f4-4521-9932-840cead6743e"),
    "Data" : {
        "I" : [
            {
                "k" : "LRI39",
                "v" : [
                    {
                        "k" : ISODate("2020-03-11T20:24:41.591Z"),
                        "v" : [
                            {
                                "k" : ISODate("2020-03-11T20:24:41.594Z"),
                                "v" : {
                                    "Source" : 1,
                                    "Value" : 19
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "k" : ISODate("2020-01-22T11:37:23.393Z"),
                        "v" : [
                            {
                                "k" : ISODate("2020-01-22T11:37:23.412Z"),
                                "v" : {
                                    "Source" : 1,
                                    "Value" : 20
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

I have been able to generate a document which is basically what you see from "Data" to the end of the sample, being the entire record for LRI39, using:

```
db.threetier.aggregate([
{   
    $project: {
        "Data.I": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$Data.I",
                as: "item",
                cond: {
                    $eq: [ "$$item.k", "LRI39" ]                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

However, no matter what I do, I cannot seem to return any subset of the records of the middle array: I get the 2020-03-11 and 2020-01-22 elements or I get nothing.

I have tried adding stages like the below to the projection above, figuring that I would get 1 record (the 2020-01-22 record) but I get both. If I change the date to be in 2019, I get nothing (as expected).

```
$project: {
    "Data.I.v": {
        $filter: {
            input: "$Data.I.v",
            as: "stamp",
            cond: { $lt: [ "$$stamp.k", ISODate("2020-02-14T00:00:00Z") ] }             
        } 
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $lt: [ "Data.I.v.k", ISODate("2020-02-14T00:00:00Z") ] } } }
```

but that returns no results at all (probably because $match works on documents not arrays) as well as trying to unwind the array using `$unwind: "$Data.I.v"` before the match, but that returns nothing as well.

It seems like I am missing something fundamental here. I do realize that Mongo is designed (I think) to have those array items as documents, but I do want to see if this will work as is.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to unwind both `Data.I` and `Data.I.v`, so that you can consider each of the sub-elements separately.

Then reverse sort by the date field.
Group by the _id and key, selecting only the first document in each group.
Finally, replaceRoot so the return is just the selected document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$Data.I"},
  {$unwind: "$Data.I.v"},
  {$sort: {"Data.I.v.k": -1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        key: "$Data.I.k"
      },
      document: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$document"}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QUwtzRrCexc)

Comment: Thanks much for providing an answer. Things are starting to gel in my mind as to how to use MQL - bit by bit.